# IE 11 giving "invalid calling object" when try to call HTTP get request

Tags: angular, httpclient, internet-explorer-11

I am using Angular 5 and HttpClient to make HTTP requests. When I try call GET request in google chrome its working fine, but in IE 11 its giving error as "invalid calling object".

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

 this.httpClient.get(url).subscribe(
  (response) => {
     console.log(response);
  },
  (err) => {
    console.log(err);
  }
)
```

Comment: This error is not related to your http request, there must be something else wrong in you code. IE and edge generate this error for multiple reasons. You should search for the reasons of "invalid calling object" and validate your code accordingly.

Comment: I debug my code, when it caught this line `this.httpClient.get(url).subscribe` then only its throwing an error.

Comment: We tried to test this code and find that code is working fine. https://textuploader.com/108g1 When we test the code we got 'NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient' error. We add import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'; in app.module.ts file and add  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,....
  ], in app.module.ts file which fix that error.

Comment: I notice that you posted another question for IE and angular some days ago. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58074988/angular-5-application-not-working-in-ie-11 as you had posted this thread i assume that you fixed the issue. I suggest  you to share the solution and mark your answer in that thread.

Comment: I got the issue. It is because of pace.min.js library.

Comment: From your last comment, it looks like you found the cause for the issue. I suggest you to post your solution as an answer and try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Also try to post solution in your previous thread. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my `index.html` file, `pace.min.js` library was there and it was loading before Angular Zone. So it's giving error when trying to call any HTTP request. I removed this library from `index.html` file. It solves my problem.

Comment: Hi, i have same issue but my index.html file doesn't has this library, do you have an idea why i get this error?